# Как удалить запись массива из сессии - PHP

Tags: php, массивы, сессия

есть вот такой массив в котором лежит 3 товара и передается через `$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][]`:

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["variant_id"]=>
    int(154)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lvl"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["variant_id"]=>
    int(157)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lvl"]=>
    int(6)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["variant_id"]=>
    int(167)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lvl"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Как мне удалить товар с `variant_id = 157`, то-есть весь массив [1], но я знаю только `variant_id`. Буду благодарен за вашу помощь!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как вариант можно через цикл:

```
$arr = [
    ['variant_id' => 154, 'amount' => 1, 'lvl' => 1],
    ['variant_id' => 157, 'amount' => 1, 'lvl' => 6],
    ['variant_id' => 167, 'amount' => 1, 'lvl' => 0]
];

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value['variant_id'] == 157)
        unset($arr[$key]);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Второй вариант с помощью функции `array_filter`:

```
$id = 157;

$arr = array_filter($arr, function ($x) use ($id) {
    return $x['variant_id'] !== $id;
});

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете использовать, к примеру, функцию [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) и включить туда более сложную логику, если понадобится. Ну смотрите.

```
$resultArray = array_filter($sessionArray, function ($value) use ($toDelete) {
    return $value['variant_id'] !== $toDelete
});
```

Объяснение: `$sessionArray` ваши исходные данные, а `$toDelete` значение, которое нужно отбросить. Соответственно, вы можете оформить анонимную функцию отдельно и использовать многократно передавая то, что вам нужно удалить, а если быть точнее, то в данном контексте вы фильтруете свой ассоциативный массив, оставляя что вам нужно. Вы можете передать в `use`, например, еще одно значение, которое будет являться ключом, который вам нужно будет отфильтровать и тогда сможете этой функцией, передавая ей соответствующие значения, добиваться фильтрации любых полей по заданным значениям.

Answer (score 3):

Можно через поиск:

```
$arr = [
    ['variant_id' => 154, 'amount' => 1, 'lvl' => 1],
    ['variant_id' => 157, 'amount' => 1, 'lvl' => 6],
    ['variant_id' => 167, 'amount' => 1, 'lvl' => 0]
];

$id = 157;

if(($key = array_search($id,array_column($arr, 'variant_id'))) !== FALSE){
    unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

Будет быстрее, чем `filter`

Comment: Это вы, со своих побуждений так решили? Как минимум у вас 2 вызова функций, за место 1 с `array_filter`, да и при больших массивах, ваш вариант проиграет в разы... ну а `foreach` - должен обыграть оба варианта. `array_filter:` 4.053 
`array_search`: 6.914 
`foreach`: 1.192

Comment: @And вы забываете что `array_filter` формирует новый массив, а потом его отдает и переприсваивает, вызывает каждый раз функцию и в нее передает 2 параметра. в то время как `array_search` в связке с `array_column` работают на низком уровне, я не знаю как вы там тестите, но: `array_search: 2.3`, а `array_filter: 3.3`

Comment: @And вы кстати не первый раз лезете со своими комментариями, вечно вам не нравится, и вечно почему-то вы не правы. Надеюсь я вас переубедил: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a31b78eda3e165d5428fd331a732a877aba5467 и вот второй: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86316421d49556d569d371897e9d3f06d8fcfce2 - тут вообще разница вышла аж в 0.4. P.S. от размера массива не зависит ничего, array_search всегда будет быстрее

Comment: Вы действительно думаете что автору вопроса интересна производительность ? :)  Однако мне, например, очень интересен ваш спор.  array_filter более понятен для чтения, однако если мы имеем дело с десятками тысяч значений массива, то я сделаю себе заметку использовать search и column вместе. Это отличная находка. Спасибо!
Однако более сложная логика похоже недоступна.

Comment: @zalex надо привыкать: чуть чуть сэкономил там, чуть чуть - там. в итоге уже пару десятых секунды уже в кармане. Когда речь будет идти с десятками тысяч - то возможно там будет свое оптимальное решение (все зависит от случая) но search и column в голове конечно держать можно :)